# How can I get the load average (and ONLY the load average) under Solaris?

Tags: terminal, solaris

I'm looking for the equivilent of `cat /proc/loadavg` under Linux or `sysctl -n vm.loadavg` under FreeBSD, but for Solaris. Solaris doesn't have either `/proc/loadavg` or `sysctl`.

I don't want the output of `w` or `uptime`, I want *just* the load averages. For example, I want:

```
0.53 0.39 0.80
```

Not:

```
13:30:44 up 51 days,  8:43,  2 users,  load average: 0.46, 0.39, 0.79
```

What terminal command will provide me with the 1, 5 and 10 minute load averages, and *only* the load averages, under Solaris?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk to return only the last 3 fields from uptime:

```
uptime | awk '{print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$(NF-0)}'
```

EDIT:

If you don't want the commas, you can use sed or tr to remove those:

```
uptime | awk '{print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$(NF-0)}' | tr "," " "

uptime | awk '{print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$(NF-0)}' | sed 's/,/ /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same format, but perhaps usable depending on what you want to do with it:

```
kstat -p 'unix:0:system_misc:avenrun*' | \
 awk '{printf "%s %.2f\n", $1, $2 / 256.0}'
```

The raw output from the kstat command (described in the [kstat(1m) man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/kstat-1m.html#scrolltoc)) is:

```
% kstat -p 'unix:0:system_misc:avenrun*'
unix:0:system_misc:avenrun_15min    42
unix:0:system_misc:avenrun_1min 17
unix:0:system_misc:avenrun_5min 25
```

Dividing the kstats by 256 provides the more familiar output.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently people have written their own [loadavg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loadavgsolaris/)

Comment: Ug, cronjob to run every minute, no thanks, there must be a better way!